# Cython: How can I create a .pxd-file for Code including an Enum?

Tags: cython, header-files

I am trying to "cythonize" the following example code, which includes an instance of an Enum class:

```
from enum import Enum
class AnimalType(Enum):
    Shark = 0
    Fish = 1

class Animal:
    def __init__(self, animal_type: AnimalType, weight: float):
        self.animal_type = animal_type
        self.weight = weight
```

Creating a .pyx-file with type declarations is easy:

```
cpdef enum AnimalType:
    Shark = 0
    Fish = 1

cdef class Animal:
    cdef double weight
    cdef AnimalType animal_type

    def __init__(self, animal_type: AnimalType, weight: float):
        self.animal_type = animal_type
        self.weight = weight
```

However, I am unable to split the .pyx file into a .pyx and .pxd (header) file. Can you please help me define a .pxd-file for my example ?

Edit: I have read https://groups.google.com/g/cython-users/c/ZoLsLHwnUY4. It might not be possible to do that ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me without doing anything special:

testenum.pxd:

```
cpdef enum AnimalType:
    Shark = 0
    Fish = 1
```

(You could also put the `cdef` parts of `Animal` there if you want to share the Cython definition of that too).

testenum.pyx:

```
# no need to cimport testenum - this happens implicitly

cdef class Animal:
    cdef double weight   # omit this if you put it in the pxd file
    cdef AnimalType animal_type   # omit this if you put it in the pxd file

    def __init__(self, animal_type: AnimalType, weight: float):
        self.animal_type = animal_type
        self.weight = weight
```

someotherfile.pyx:

```
from testenum cimport AnimalType

cdef class C:
    cdef AnimalType at
```

Comment: from testenum import AnimalType works as well.

Comment: I thought that you can only define types and type declarations within a pxd-file. Didnt expect to be able to set up an enum and then import/cimport anywhere I want. But it works so...

Comment: The difference between `import` and `cimport` is that with `cimport` Cython knows about the type as it compiles. Which is sometimes useful